# Merge dataframe rows if 2 columns are equal (but different order)

Tags: python, pandas

In a padas dataframe, I want to check if I have rows like this:

```
Var1   Var2   Value1   Value2
a      b      1       NaN
b      a      NaN     2
```

And if it's the case, merge them like this:

```
Var1   Var2   Value1   Value2
a      b      1       2
```

Some idea?

If Var1 & Var2 == Var2 & Var1...?

Comment: What is the logic, what are these rows, where are they stored, how they are parsed, what type is used to define them???????????????

Comment: If you mean 'pandas dataframe', then please write that, also tag this [tag:pandas]. cc: @sudden_appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby on sets created from Var1 and Var2 -- sets are useful as set(a,b) is the same as set(b,a). But sets by themselves cannot be used in indexing as they are not hashable, so we need to use frozenset. Once grouped we can add the Value's and take first element for Var's. In short, you can do this:

```
grouper = [frozenset(t) for t in df[['Var1','Var2']].values]
df.groupby(grouper, as_index = False).agg({'Var1':'first', 'Var2':'first', 'Value1':'sum', 'Value2':'sum'})
```

output

```
    Var1    Var2    Value1  Value2
0   a       b       1.0     2.0
```